# Symfony 6/Pimcore - How to override a bundle's configuration from another bundle

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

I have created a Symfony bundle here https://github.com/TorqIT/pimcore-flysystem-azure-bundle that is meant to allow Pimcore (https://pimcore.com/en) to utilize Flysystem to read/write files in an Azure Storage Account. For those who aren't aware, Pimcore is a Symfony-based PIM/CMS/DAM. It contains its own Flysystem configuration, the configuration for which can be seen here https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/11.x/bundles/CoreBundle/config/pimcore/flysystem.yaml.

My aim is to have my custom bundle's Flysystem configuration override Pimcore's. I am doing this by simply placing my bundle's `config.yaml` in the `config/pimcore` directory. It is inconsistent in overriding, however. Sometimes I will find files being written to the filesystem rather than to Azure, but I'm unsure what is causing this. Also, whenever I run `bin/console debug:container flysystem` or `bin/console debug:config flysystem`, sometimes I will see the `LocalFilesystemAdapter` being loaded (i.e. from Pimcore's `flysystem.yaml`), and sometimes my custom `TorqAzureBlobStorageAdapter`.

I have looked into Compiler Passes (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) and attempted to implement one like this:

```
final class FlysystemAzurePass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $pimcoreAdapterServiceIdsToCustomAdapters = [
            // Mapping the Pimcore Flysystem Adapter service IDs to our custom adapter classes (see services.yaml)
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.document_static.storage' => 'document_static_adapter',
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.asset.storage' => 'assets_adapter',
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.asset_cache.storage' => 'asset_cache_adapter',
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.thumbnail.storage' => 'thumbnail_adapter',
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.version.storage' => 'version_adapter',
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.recycle_bin.storage' => 'recycle_bin_adapter',
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.admin.storage' => 'admin_adapter',
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.email_log.storage' => 'email_log_adapter',
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.temp.storage' => 'tmp_adapter',
            'flysystem.adapter.pimcore.application_log.storage' => 'application_log_adapter',
        ];
        foreach ($pimcoreAdapterServiceIdsToCustomAdapters as $pimcoreServiceId => $customAdapter) {
            $definition = $container->getDefinition($pimcoreServiceId);
            $definition->setClass($container->getDefinition($customAdapter)->getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

However, this results in errors about my custom adapter class not being passed the correct arguments when the container builds it:
`Message: TorqIT\FlysystemAzureBundle\TorqAzureBlobStorageAdapter::__construct(): Argument #1 ($client) must be of type MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy, string given, called in /var/www/html/var/cache/dev/ContainerQ320XmG/getPimcore_Asset_StorageService.php on line 29`

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Adding some more context - when I debug, I can see that the arguments being passed to my custom adapter inside the container are the parameters usually intended for the `LocalFilesystemAdapter`. I have attempted to use the `setArgument` method in my Compiler Pass to override the arguments, but the container still loads the original arguments, I am assuming due to the order that things are being loaded. I'm unsure if there's another spot I should be doing this, or if I'm off-base entirely on how to override the original config file.

Comment: Your `TorqAzureBlobStorageAdapter` expects a client as argument. Maybe you need generate a factory class for your adapter and call `$defnition->setFactory('@myservicefactory')`. Another simple approach is to redefine your class constructor to receive a string.

Comment: Hi @SilvioQ I've just added more context on the arguments that the container is passing to my adapter

Comment: I know you're looking for a Bundle, but have you tried with configuration/forking to see your concept is working first of all?

Comment: @CAAHS we own the bundle. And it works some of the time. Even without the compiler pass in place, >80% of the time the flysystem config loads properly and the filesystem operations are redirected to our azure storage adapaters. But occasionally, the appear to instead fallback to the default configuration and write to the local filesystem. We're not sure if it's a configuration priority issue depending on the order the bundles are loaded or something else.

Comment: @IronSean: This is what I meant: Drop the bundle idea (don't look for it), just hard-encode, overwrite the default configuration and see if it works all the time or not. Then when proven, re-consider how to implement that in a bundle. Hope this works better for trouble-shooting.